# Como debugar uma requisição ajax para uma rota laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

estou fazendo uma requisição AJAX em uma rota, utilizando o laravel, da seguinte forma:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url: "../controle/pendentes/concluirVarias",
            type: "POST",
            data: {  ids: arrayIds , _token: '{!! csrf_token() !!}' },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    );
```

ArrayIds é um array que está declarado acima, recebendo alguns pushs.

O arquivo de rotas possui a seguinte rota:

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => '/controle'], function() {
    //rota que irá marcar alguma carteirinha pendente como 'concluída'
    Route::post('/pendentes/concluirVarias/', function() {

        $input = Input::only('ids'); //recebe um array de ids
        $input = $input['ids']; 

    //percorre todos os ids e seta 'pendente' = 0
        foreach($input as $id) {
            $aluno = new App\Aluno();
            $aluno = $aluno->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
            $aluno->pendente = '0';
            $aluno->save();
        }

    });
    }
```

Nenhum aluno está tendo a variável 'pendente' alterada para 0.

No console, ao acionar a função que possui o AJAX, tenho o retorno de um HTML da página atual.

Em Network, após acionar o ajax, aparece 'concluirVarias' em 'name'. Quando clico, para ver o preview, vejo a própria página HTML atual.

Em headers, na parte de 'form Data', está passando normalmente o array, pois vejo escrito:

> ids[]:30
>   ids[]:13
>   ids[]:17
>   ids[]:12
>   ids[]:10
>   ids[]:5
>   ids[]:3
>   ids[]:16
>   ids[]:20
>   ids[]:21
>   _token:Jg1G2UpZHRmcMdcBqVDJCIuT8yUxN15Kt0BNaBRO

Como eu faço para debugar a parte de rotas, por exemplo, adicionar um dd($input) ou algo assim, pra eu conseguir ver o que está realmente sendo passado para a rota?

Obrigado.

Comment: `url: "../controle/pendentes/concluirVarias"`, está errado assim deveria ser `url: "/pendentes/concluirVarias/"`, ou seja, o nome do caminho é inválido

Comment: Desculpe, não coloquei que essa URL está em um group '/controle'.

Comment: Agora está uma confusão porque cade a requisição POST? A Route::post??? cade?

Comment: Realmente. É post.

Comment: a url: "/controle/pendentes/concluir/1" ou url: "/controle/pendentes/concluir/2" é assim a rota então

Comment: Não. /controle/pendentes/concluirVarias. Não havia visto que tinha pegado a parte errada do código original. Perdão.

Comment: Você pode debugar essa parte: **`Input::only('ids')`**.
Depois de passar esse valor para a variável $input escreva `dd($input)`.

Comment: Fiz isso, mas não deu nenhuma diferença na saída. Ainda continua retornando a página inteira no console. Engraçado que se eu alterar o nome da url para uma que não existe, ele continua retornando a mesma coisa.